# Can't find documents searching by ObjectId using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

```
  Campaign.find {client_id:req.param('client_id')}, (error, campaigns) ->
    if error
      response =
        error: error.message
    else
      for campaign in campaigns
        query =
          campaign_id: campaign._id
        console.log query
        CampaignResponse.find query, (err, campaignResponsesCount) ->
          console.log campaignResponsesCount

      response = campaigns

    res.json response
```

For some reason, this returns **no** results. However, there are items in `CampaignResponse` with that specific `campaign._id`. I'm pretty sure this is an issue with types and casting, but I can't figure out what to do.

Any help?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

A couple tips:

- Try running the same query from mongodb at the command line, see if you get any results.
- Is the "campaign_id" defined as an ObjectId in your schema? If so, try searching using the ObjectId type.

For example:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
var query = { campaign_id: new ObjectId(campaign._id) };
```

Comment: Any idea why Mongoose inserts using ObjectId and then not use ObjectId when querying?

Comment: Note that the following statements are equivalent :

    var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').BSONPure.ObjectID;

Comment: 'new' may not be needed; `var query = { campaign_id: ObjectId(campaign._id) };`

Comment: @YasinOkumuş new is needed otherwise we'll get error : TypeError: Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: @MohamedHamzaoui Thank you, it has been a lot of time since my comment and things may have been changed sure :) I don't even remember my comment actually and I haven't used that for a long time. Thanks for info

Answer (score 52):

Just to improve the previous (correct) answer, i use on my projects :

```
String.prototype.toObjectId = function() {
  var ObjectId = (require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId);
  return new ObjectId(this.toString());
};

// Every String can be casted in ObjectId now
console.log('545f489dea12346454ae793b'.toObjectId());
```

Comment: I'd suggest checking for such a method's presence first:

`if (!String.prototype.toObjectId) { /* your implementation */ }`

Comment: @Paul Rad Where would you suggest it would be best to implement this?

Comment: @JakubBarczyk I'm a bit late but if you're extending built-in objects, it is actually **not** a good idea to check for their existence first *unless your script is a polyfill*, as TC39 may extend the JavaScript API in the future. This is the reason that `Array.includes` is named as it is, instead of the more fitting name `Array.contains`: Older versions of MooTools already added such a property onto `Array.prototype`, and checked to see if it existed first. MooTools' algorithm differed from the spec algorithm, and was used often enough that adding the spec version broke a lot of the web.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using ObjectId to find by comparing your parameters simply use

`Campaign.findById {req.param('client_id'),function(err,docs)}....`

when finding docs using objectId findById is the most efficient way of all...

Comment: This is good for the _id property of a document. but the OP's example is querying a relation - it's looking for the client_id property.