# Mongo - Does not return data when type is NumberLong

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose with nodejs to query the data from the database, i have the data in the database as follows which has the following userId:

[image]

**Code:**

```
 return dbService.query(userModel, {
                        'userId': idRetrieved
                    }, {});
```

Implementation of query method:

```
 query: function (model, conditon, options) {
            console.log(conditon, options);
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                options = options || {};

                model.find(conditon, {}, options).exec(function (error, data) {
                    if (error) {                       
                        reject(error);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                })
            })
        }
```

**Schema**

```
var userToSchema = dbService.createEntityDef({
            userId: {
                type: Number
            },

            firstName: {
                type: String
            },
            lastName: {
                type: String
            },
            urlPicture: {
                type: String
            }

        });
```

above does not return any data.

Comment: How is your mongoose schema defined?

Comment: updated the schema

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find documents searching by ObjectId using Mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878557/cant-find-documents-searching-by-objectid-using-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

'userId' field's type is not Number. You should you use 'mongoose-long' npm module to define the type for 'userId' field