# Mongoose Model.find by id donsent return desired data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

MongoDB with Mongoose API inst returning the data I need
the next line is the copy-paste of the property of the data I'm trying to access and returns fine with a find all

```
"_id": "62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7"
```

queries tried as first and only argument in both Subscriber.findOne() and Subscriber.findById() include:

```
{ _id: ObjectId('62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7') }

{ _id: '62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7' }

{
      _id: {
        $oid: '62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7',
      },
    }

'62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7'
```

Using MongoSH i can successfully get the data using this query
db.subscribers.findOne({_id: ObjectId("62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7")})
but using it on Mongoose throws a ObjectId not defined error.

```
    function getSubscriber(req, res, next) {
      let subscriber;
      try {
        //ins't working also on runtime only one of these lines is not commented
        subscriber = Subscriber.findOne({_id: ObjectId('62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7')});
        // also didn't work
        subscriber = Subscriber.findById(req.params.id);
        if (subscriber == null) {
          return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cannot find subscriber' });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: `error ${err} ${req.params.id}` });
      }
      res.subscriber = subscriber;
      next();
    }
```

Lastly, I know I'm getting to run the middleware as the name property is read after and the query is printed

```
    router.get('/:id', getSubscriber, (req, res) => {
      res.send(`Hola ${res.body} ${res.subscriber}`);
    });
```

Output:

```
Hola undefined Subscriber.findOne({})
```

I'm trying to get to search with something like .findById(req.params.id) but even using the value directly isn't working.

Comment: `subscriber = await Subscriber.findOne...`

Comment: Maybe you can code with the callback associated with the `find...` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing ObjectId from mongoose that's why you are getting error of ObjectId not defined. Where you are using `ObjectId('62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7')` You have to use it from mongoose as ObjectId is declared in mongoose module. So need to import mongoose first.

Import mongoose at the top of the file.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

Then use it to the query.

```
subscriber = Subscriber.findOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('62657d142ac1ad1cab8ca7f7')})
```

[This might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7882881/13299299)

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getSubscriber(req, res) {
    const { id } = req.params;
    try {
        const subscriber = await Subscriber.findById(id).exec();
        if (subscriber == null) {
          return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cannot find subscriber' });
        }
        res.subscriber = subscriber;
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: `error ${err}` });
    }
}
```